# mysql orderby doesn't work on operations in the select part of the query?

Tags: mysql

I managed to write the query below, which nearly works, the problem being any null values zeroed out by the `IFNULL(likes.num, 0)` get put at the end of the result table.

```
SELECT t.*, IFNULL(likes.num, 0)
FROM `textagname` as t
LEFT JOIN likes
ON t.tex = likes.tex
ORDER BY num DESC
```

Is there another way to write this query, not like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, IFNULL(likes.num, 0)
    FROM `textagname` as t
    LEFT JOIN likes
    ON t.tex = likes.tex
)
ORDER BY d.num DESC
```

Preferably a way that doesn't make it take much longer.

Comment: What is wrong with the values zeroed out to appear at the end of the result table? You are ordering them in descending order, 0 is smaller than any positive values, are there any negative values and the zeroes appear after them?

Comment: @SanSS likes.num can be any positive or negative integer including zero. I would like the zeros to be between the positive and negative numbers.

Comment: Does `ORDER BY IFNULL(likes.num, 0)` work in MySQL?

Comment: @Toni That is basically what I ended up doing. I'll post below.

Answer (score 1):

The trick was to order by the generated value not the one coming from the table. Notice the addition of numLikes below.

```
SELECT t.*, IFNULL(likes.num, 0) as numLikes
FROM `textagname` as t
LEFT JOIN likes
ON t.tex = likes.tex
ORDER BY numLikes DESC
```